# How to query an extremelly large online csv file with python everyday for new information?

Tags: python, csv

I'm using python to analyse covid-19 data in Brazil. The federal government shares a csv file with the record of each vaccination in the country. This csv file has over 170GB.

For my study I need to query this csv file to obtain the `quantity` of vaccination grouped by `city` and by `day`. In sql it would be something like:

```
select city, day, Count(*)
from my_table
group by city, day
```

How can I extract this information from the online csv file since it is so large?

This file is **updated daily**, since new people get vaccinated every day. It means that new rows are appended to the file every day.

I'd like to extract/update the counters daily. Is there a smart/quick way to check for the new rows in the csv file and update the counters?

*I cannot download the whole file everyday and import it to a database.*

The data is available here: https://qsprod.saude.gov.br/extensions/covid-19_html/covid-19_html.html in the link `Dados Completos` a 153468857093 byte CSV on S3.

The input file sample is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LRVJMKeE0wzuGshmfsI7pnfpHA800iph/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please upload a sample of the input file.

Comment: How about just upload the CSV into a SQL database? It would probably turn into less than 170GB with the right compression settings

Comment: @OneCricketeer – this is not a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424771/parallel-processing-of-a-large-csv-file-in-python since that's talking about an offline file.

Comment: @AKX The file will need to be downloaded (or streamed if server allows), regardless

Comment: Again, if you are comfortable with SQL, why don't you import the data to a database and use that? It's going to be a lot more efficient than using Python directly on the CSV file, and easily worth the effort if you have more than 2-3 queries.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Indeed, if the server supports streaming, a group-by like this could be done with `for x in resp.iter_lines()` and a `Counter`. That's why this is different.

Comment: The sample is google drive is not something that represents your question, Please upload a better sample.

Comment: If my nonexistent Portuguese is correct, the data OP wants is the `Dados Completos` link from https://opendatasus.saude.gov.br/en/dataset/covid-19-vacinacao/resource/ef3bd0b8-b605-474b-9ae5-c97390c197a8 which points to a 153468857093 byte CSV on S3. Could be streamed, could be chunked :) Also, I imagine the other Dados files are per-region or something, so could also be parallelized over them.

Comment: @AKX yes.. but the question is about different data struct. Anyway - I think *The Aelfinn*  answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371043/use-python-requests-to-download-csv can work here very well.

Comment: @balderman Indeed. As I said in a comment above, `resp.iter_lines()` and a counter.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems to do the trick (assuming you have enough memory and a stable Internet connection to process the file in a single request).

The data in the `Counter` ends up being e.g.

```
Counter({
  ('BRASILIA', '2021-03-18'): 2,
  ('SAO PAULO', '2021-03-26'): 1,
  ('INDAIATUBA', '2021-08-09'): 1,
  ...
})
```

You'll want to remove the `islice()` to process more than the 100 first rows, of course.

```
import pickle
from collections import Counter
from itertools import islice

import requests
import csv

DATA_URL = "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ckan.saude.gov.br/PNI/vacina/completo/2021-11-15/part-00000-d217d29f-9db0-4280-ad94-ff0afe3d8b11-c000.csv"

resp = requests.get(DATA_URL, stream=True)
resp.raise_for_status()
resp.encoding = "UTF-8"

counter = Counter()

for row in islice(
    csv.DictReader(resp.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True), delimiter=";"), 100
):
    key = (row.get("estabelecimento_municipio_nome"), row.get("vacina_dataaplicacao"))
    counter[key] += 1


with open("data.pickle", "wb") as outf:
    pickle.dump(counter, outf)
```

For anything more complex, I really would recommend downloading the file and `LOAD`ing it e.g. to a PostgreSQL table.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Now lets say I have to update my counters daily, since everyday new people get vaccinated. Is there a smart/quick way to check for the new rows in the csv file?

Comment: Well, _if_ you are sure that new rows get added to the end of the file (which probably isn't the case since the 100 first rows include entries for 2021-03 and 2021-08) you could keep track of the size of the old file, then only request new bytes and so on... But it doesn't seem like that that's the case.