# Multiprocessing with progress

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, progress

I've never worked with `multiprocessing` before so bear with me if I'm asking a basic question.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364667/464744) provided a very nice processing class that I adapted to my needs and it works very well. I'm trying to implement a basic progress bar which I'm testing using `print` statements, but it is not working at all (no output whatsoever).

My current code is this:

```
class ParsingMaster(object):
  def __init__(self, parser, input_file, output_file):
    self.parser = parser

    self.num_processes = cpu_count()
    self.input_file = input_file
    self.output_file = output_file

    self.input_queue = Queue()
    self.output_queue = Queue()

    self.input_size = 0

    self.input_process = Process(target=self.parse_input)
    self.output_process = Process(target=self.write_output)
    self.processes = [Process(target=self.process_row) for row in range(self.num_processes)]

    self.input_process.start()
    self.output_process.start()

    for process in self.processes:
      process.start()

    self.input_process.join()

    for process in self.processes:
      process.join()

    self.output_process.join()

  def parse_input(self):
    for index, row in enumerate(self.input_file):
      self.input_queue.put([index, row])
      self.input_size = self.input_queue.qsize()

    for i in range(self.num_processes):
      self.input_queue.put('STOP')

  def process_row(self):
    for index, row in iter(self.input_queue.get, 'STOP'):
      self.output_queue.put([index, row[0], self.parser.parse(row[1])])

    self.output_queue.put('STOP')

  def write_output(self):
    current = 0
    buffer = {}

    for works in range(self.num_processes):
      for index, id, row in iter(self.output_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        if index != current:
          buffer[index] = [id] + row
        else:
          self.output_file.writerow([id] + row)
          current += 1

          while current in buffer:
            self.output_file.writerow(buffer[current])
            del buffer[current]
            current += 1

            if self.input_size:
              print float(current * 100) / float(self.input_size)
```

After some testing, I've found some strange things:

- `self.input_size` is updated properly in `parse_input()`.
- `parse_input()` ends while `write_output()` is still running.
- `write_output()` *always* reports that `self.input_size = 0`.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here? Any help is helpful, so thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.input_size` is a process-local variable, each process will have its own copy. According to the [multiprocessing documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), you need to wrap your data into containers like `Value` and `Array` to make it shared.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure it out myself about an hour ago, but it's good to know I was going in the right direction ;)