# Is there a cost to calling python multiprocessing .join() method

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

My question is inspired by a comment on the [solving embarassingly parallel problem with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359253/solving-embarassingly-parallel-problems-using-python-multiprocessing) post.

I am asking about the general case where python multiprocessing is used to (1) read data from file, (2) manipulate data, (3) write results to file. In the case I describe, data that is read from file is passed to a queue A in (1) and fetched from this queue A in (2). (2) also passes results to a separate queue B and (3) fetches results from this queue B to write them to file.

When (1) is done, it passes a STOP signal* to queue A so (2) knows queue A is empty. (2) then terminates and passes a STOP signal to queue B so (3) knows queue B is empty and terminates when it has used up the results queue.

So is there any need to call the multiprocessing [.join() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) on (1) and (2)? I would have thought that (2) will not finish until (1) finishes and sends a STOP signal? For (3) it makes sense to wait as any subsequent instructions might else proceed without (3).

But maybe calling the .join() method costs nothing and can be used just to avoid having to think about it?

---

*actually, the STOP signal consists of a sequence of N stop signals where N is equivalent to the number of processes running in (2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join), it is safe to call `join` multiple times - this suggests that if `p` has already stopped, `p.join()` will return immediately. This means that if you expect `p` to have already stopped by this time, the cost of joining it should be negligible. If `p` *hasn't* stopped (as you say you expect the writer process might not have), there is a potential cost to joining it depending on what your main process needs to do. If it does any user interaction, it will appear hung. If that is a problem, you might consider this type of pattern:

```
while p.is_alive():
   iterate_mainloop()
   p.join(small_timeout)
```

But if that process doesn't do user interaction, joining the others should be fine. That seems to be the most likely situation here - if you can afford to be blocked waiting for a disk read, you should also be fine waiting for another process to complete (modulo any defensive timeouts in case it misbehaves).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I had seen `join` can be called multiple times but not made the connection.