# Q: How to write a function output in a .CSV file with multi-threading / multiprocessing ? (Using a String array as input)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I am coding a little web scraper where I would like to implement multiprocessing / multi-threading.

I have written my function webScraper() which receives a String with a website URL as input, scrapes some domain data and writes that data to a CSV file, line by line (for each domain).

The input data with all the URLs is saved in a String array like this :
`urls = ["google.com", "yahoo.com", "bing.com"]`. (I consider changing to URL import from CSV file.)

How can I use multiprocessing and write the function output to a CSV file without having inconsistencies and index out of bounds errors? I found a nice looking script, which seems to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately, I just switched to Python from Java a few days ago and can't figure out what I need to change exactly.

So basically, I just want to change the script below, so that it calls my function `webScraper(url)` for each URL that is in my String array `urls` or Input CSV file. The script should then write the function output for each array item line by line into my CSV (if I understood the code correctly).

That's the code I am working on ([Thanks to hbar for the nice code!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359253/solving-embarassingly-parallel-problems-using-python-multiprocessing/2364667#2364667))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# multiproc_sums.py
"""A program that reads integer values from a CSV file and writes out their
sums to another CSV file, using multiple processes if desired.
"""

import csv
import multiprocessing
import optparse
import sys

NUM_PROCS = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def make_cli_parser():
    """Make the command line interface parser."""
    usage = "\n\n".join(["python %prog INPUT_CSV OUTPUT_CSV",
            __doc__,
            """
ARGUMENTS:
    INPUT_CSV: an input CSV file with rows of numbers
    OUTPUT_CSV: an output file that will contain the sums\
"""])
    cli_parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
    cli_parser.add_option('-n', '--numprocs', type='int',
            default=NUM_PROCS,
            help="Number of processes to launch [DEFAULT: %default]")
    return cli_parser

class CSVWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, numprocs, infile, outfile):
        self.numprocs = numprocs
        self.infile = open(infile)
        self.outfile = outfile
        self.in_csvfile = csv.reader(self.infile)
        self.inq = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.outq = multiprocessing.Queue()

        self.pin = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.parse_input_csv, args=())
        self.pout = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.write_output_csv, args=())
        self.ps = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=self.sum_row, args=())
                        for i in range(self.numprocs)]

        self.pin.start()
        self.pout.start()
        for p in self.ps:
            p.start()

        self.pin.join()
        i = 0
        for p in self.ps:
            p.join()
            print "Done", i
            i += 1

        self.pout.join()
        self.infile.close()

    def parse_input_csv(self):
            """Parses the input CSV and yields tuples with the index of the row
            as the first element, and the integers of the row as the second
            element.

            The index is zero-index based.

            The data is then sent over inqueue for the workers to do their
            thing.  At the end the input process sends a 'STOP' message for each
            worker.
            """
            for i, row in enumerate(self.in_csvfile):
                row = [ int(entry) for entry in row ]
                self.inq.put( (i, row) )

            for i in range(self.numprocs):
                self.inq.put("STOP")

    def sum_row(self):
        """
        Workers. Consume inq and produce answers on outq
        """
        tot = 0
        for i, row in iter(self.inq.get, "STOP"):
                self.outq.put( (i, sum(row)) )
        self.outq.put("STOP")

    def write_output_csv(self):
        """
        Open outgoing csv file then start reading outq for answers
        Since I chose to make sure output was synchronized to the input there
        is some extra goodies to do that.

        Obviously your input has the original row number so this is not
        required.
        """
        cur = 0
        stop = 0
        buffer = {}
        # For some reason csv.writer works badly across processes so open/close
        # and use it all in the same process or else you'll have the last
        # several rows missing
        outfile = open(self.outfile, "w")
        self.out_csvfile = csv.writer(outfile)

        #Keep running until we see numprocs STOP messages
        for works in range(self.numprocs):
            for i, val in iter(self.outq.get, "STOP"):
                # verify rows are in order, if not save in buffer
                if i != cur:
                    buffer[i] = val
                else:
                    #if yes are write it out and make sure no waiting rows exist
                    self.out_csvfile.writerow( [i, val] )
                    cur += 1
                    while cur in buffer:
                        self.out_csvfile.writerow([ cur, buffer[cur] ])
                        del buffer[cur]
                        cur += 1

        outfile.close()

def main(argv):
    cli_parser = make_cli_parser()
    opts, args = cli_parser.parse_args(argv)
    if len(args) != 2:
        cli_parser.error("Please provide an input file and output file.")

    c = CSVWorker(opts.numprocs, args[0], args[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The whole thing wouldn't really be a problem for me, if there was no writting to a CSV file involved in the multiprocessing. I already tried a different solution Python Map Pool ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python/28463266#28463266)) but without success. I think there were inconsistencies among the Pools which led to errors.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is by using multiprocessing to do the web scraping, and then using a single process to write out to a csv. I'm willing to bet that the scraping is the time consuming part, and the I/O is quick. Below is a snippet of code that uses Pool.map to multiprocess your function.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import csv

pool = mp.Pool( processes=mp.cpu_count() ) 
# or however many processors you can support

scraped_data = pool.map( webScraper, urls )

with open('out.csv') as outfile:
    wr = csv.writer(outfile)
    wr.writerow(scraped_data)
```